# Are there any methods to read char while user input a text?

Tags: c++, c++11

Are there any methods to read char while user enter a text? C++. For example, how to stop input of text when user enter a numeral (not letter)?

Comment: while? so asynchronously?

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any methods to read char while user enter a text? C++. For example, how to stop input of text when user enter a numeral (not letter)?

No there aren't any methods provided with the c++ standard I/O library functions to check single character inputs immediately.

That's OS specific and you need to access the keystrokes from a keyboard device directly.

---

There are a number of functions to validate input after it was commited by the user with the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, but not immediately ***while typing***.

Comment: If the process is in a loop, you can use  _kbhit() function. It detects to key pushed (char), Then you can control each char if it is a letter or not                          if (_kbhit() ch = getchar();

Comment: @Ibrahim `_kbhit()` isn't a standard c++ function. That's specific for (old) Windows `conio.h` stuff.

Comment: If you don't mind, a slight mention of how `stdin` works might make this much more informative

Comment: @PasserBy Feel free to write your own answer explaining that in detail.

Comment: I feel like a new answer would be stepping so much on your toes :P

Comment: @PasserBy No, if it adds value here certainly not.

Answer (score 2):

There are no C++ standard IO functions that will give the immediate results of each keyboard stroke, only those that will read what have been typed and committed with a <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

This is due to how input works in C++: they go through `stdin`. `stdin` is a file not necessarily representing your keyboard, but when it does, it only holds the contents of what has been committed with <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Doing so has the benefit of unifying all sorts of input methods into one common interface of a file.

The non-standard functions that can read immediate keystrokes (e.g. `getch` in `conio.h`) reads input differently: it detects the presence of keystrokes. Since C++ as a language doesn't want to include or require the notion of a keyboard, these are OS specific.

Comment: Thanks for your support <3